# Change ToggleButton state from BroadcastReceiver Class

Tags: java, android, togglebutton

i'm trying to build a radio app contains in `mainactivity` a `togglebutton` for play and pause music, and also have an notification media controller for play/pause music i want when i click pause from notification the `togglebutton` change state from true to false and vice versa.

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MyIntentSerice.myActivityforservice = this;
}
  @Subscribe
public void handlePlaybackEvent(PlaybackEvent event) {
    switch (event) {
        case PLAY:
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            break;
        case PAUSE:
            if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                mediaPlayer.start();
            break;
    }
}
 @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    try {
        MApplication.sBus.register(this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    try {
        MApplication.sBus.unregister(this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**BroadcastReceiver** class

```
public class MyIntentSerice extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String RESUME_ACTION = "RESUME_ACTION";
    public static final String STOP_ACTION = "STOP_ACTION";
    public static int REQUEST_CODE_NOTIFICATION = 1212;
    public static Activity myActivityforservice;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ToggleButton music = MyIntentSerice.myActivityforservice.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
        if (music != null && intent.getAction() != null) {
            switch (intent.getAction()) {
                case RESUME_ACTION:
                    MApplication.sBus.post(PlaybackEvent.PAUSE);
                    music.setChecked(false);
                    break;
                case STOP_ACTION:
                    MApplication.sBus.post(PlaybackEvent.PLAY);
                    music.setChecked(true);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MApplication**

```
public class MApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
    public static Bus sBus = new Bus(ThreadEnforcer.MAIN);

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sBus.register(this);
    }
}
```

**PlaybackEvent**

```
public enum PlaybackEvent {
    PLAY, PAUSE
}
```

my code doesn't work :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: `MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();` – You cannot do that. The system must handle `Activity` instantiation, or bad stuff happens, like that Exception you're getting now. That wouldn't be the same `MainActivity` instance that's currently running anyway, right? You appear to be using some sort of event bus already – `MApplication.sBus.post(...);`. Why not have `MainActivity` subscribe to that, and let it handle the toggle itself when those events are posted?

Comment: @MikeM. thanks so much for your reply i want your advice about what i do ( and it's work) firstly i create a` public static Activity myActivityforservice;` in Broadcast class  and in `onReceive` method i put  T`oggleButton music = MyIntentSerice.myActivityforservice.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);`

Comment: No, don't do that, either. You don't want to directly access `MainActivity` from your Receiver. As I mentioned, it looks like you're already using an event bus. Have `MainActivity` subscribe to that, and let it handle the toggle. What are you using that event bus for now?

Comment: @MikeM. please see my update

Comment: OK, there, in `MainActivity`. You're already subscribing, with the `handlePlaybackEvent()` method. Why can't you set the toggle there?

Comment: @MikeM. thanks so much it's works

Comment: No problem. Btw, it looks like you're using Otto there. If that's the case, you should have a look at this info from CommonsWare: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46103119/why-my-new-fragment-cant-subscribe-otto#comment79169163_46103119. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Comment: @MikeM. yes i'm using Otto library , It has problems ?

Comment: Not necessarily, but it's no longer under active development, so if you do find some issue with it, they aren't gonna fix it. I just wanted you to be aware.

Comment: @MikeM. thanks so much for your informations,i will try to use greenrobot library instead of it